# Is it possible to create secure guessing game on chain?

Tags: blockchain, cryptography

We are trying to build battleship style guessing game and on smartcontract storages/data are visible so people can easly cheat.Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: SE is a technical forum and questions must be technical in nature. This is not a technical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use commit/reveal pattern, for turn based game it works well.
Here a template in CameLIGO you would be able to adapt to your use case: https://github.com/ligolang/randomness-cameligo

Comment: I suppose we should summarize or quote from the link. However, I've noticed that the question says "battleship style guessing game" -- that's vague, but, it's not obvious to me how to implement it using commit/reveal.

Comment: You would start with:
At the beginning of the game, each player commit its grid (actually 1 chest per box batched all togeter in a transaction);
At each round, when a player announce a target square, the oponent reveal the relative chest

Comment: Makes sense... then I guess we find out at the end (after chests forced open if necessary) whether a player cheated in their setup (say, grid with no ships on it) and can punish them?